# Need to replace string with jQuery by exact match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm aware there's a few answers out there, but I can't get it to work properly.

I'm using a little script to change a few strings - but now I need to change a "0" and it wont work since the div I'm targeting also contains larger numbers. How do I do this on the exact match only, in this case a zero?

The script I'm using:

```
$( "td.stockinfo:contains('0')" ).text('*').addClass( "outofstock" );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`$.fn.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

*Script*

```
$("td.stockinfo").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == '0';
}).text('*').addClass("outofstock");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each`.

Try this:

```
$("td.stockinfo").each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == '0') {
        $(this).text('*').addClass("outofstock");
    }
});
```